# String.format not completely working?

Tags: java, string, format

```
TMP = String.format("%-25s %25s", STRING1, STRING2);
```

Whenever I print TMP, it doesn't seem to properly print the table the way I'm looking for

For example:

STRING1 = Test1 & Test12
STRING2 = Hello

```
Print:
Test1           Hello
Test12           Hello
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Avoid using all-capitals for variable names; in Java, that's a convention that indicates a constant.

Answer (score 2):

`"Test12"` has 1 more character than `"Test1"`. Try this

```
String.format("%-25s\t%25s", string1, string2);
```

Comment: I suspect a tab is very much not what the OP needs. Probably they were looking to put "Test1" and "Test12" in a 25-character space-padded column.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to make sure that there is a certain number of spaces allocated. This assures that each string will always start on the nth character.

Comment: @AlexanderKhaosGreenstein Then Peters solution is _probably_ the more likely solution here

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your String has padded spaces already

```
for (String s1 : "Test1,Test12,Test123,Test1234,Test12                    ".split(",")) {
    String tmp = String.format("%-25s %25s", s1, "hello");
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

prints

```
Test1                                         hello
Test12                                        hello
Test123                                       hello
Test1234                                      hello
Test12                                         hello
```

You can `trim()` them before trying to format them.

```
String tmp = String.format("%-25s %25s", s1.trim(), s2.trim());
```